# wifi not showing up!

Tags: 16.04, wireless, realtek

I've tried many solutions based on other's questions. Nothing seem to work!
I'm a new linux user. Don't know much about it. Please help me out.
when I typed in 
sudo lshw -C network
This is the output:

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 07
       serial: 40:b0:34:be:e7:29
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:124 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1200000-b1200fff memory:b1000000-b1003fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 3c:a0:67:fe:27:e7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.10.0-28-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.43.134 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1100000-b1103fff
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Your Realtek rtl8723be usually benefits from being instructed which antenna to use. Most wireless drivers autodetect, but rtl8723be is not yet working correctly. We can do so with a driver parameter. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=1
```

We’ve told the driver we’re using antenna 1. Is there any improvement? If not, we’ll try antenna 2:

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be ant_sel=2
```

With one of these two, you should see available networks when you click the Network Manager icon:

[image]

Whichever setting makes your wireless work is the one we’ll make permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=1"  > /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
exit
```

Of course, specify the setting that yields the best performance from your experiment above.