# RealTek Wireless network issue on my laptop with Dual Boot Ubuntu 14 and Windows 10

Tags: boot, networking, dual-boot, drivers, realtek

I was unable to see the Wireless Networks near by in Ubuntu 14 on my Dual boot (Ubuntu 14/Window 10) HP laptop. My netwotk Adapter is RealTek RTL8723BE (obtained by `lshw -C network`).
Weird thing is I was able to see and connect to my Mobile Hotspot, but the WiFi Devices near by are not even listed or seen.

I was able to see and connect to all the known networks near by when booted with Windows 10 OS.

Can Anyone please help me on this ??

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Please check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/979429/wifi-not-showing-up/979535#979535

Comment: Executed those commands able to see the networks around when ant_sel=1 is given. But I was not able to connect even when I gave the correct password.

Comment: Have you undertaken the router and CRDA steps I outlined here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/877164/cannot-connect-with-wifi-when-close-to-router/877257#877257